# Get Html page after jQuery and Javascript execution with Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I've imported the content of a webpage into a variable in python, but I'm not getting the final structure (the one that's modified by Ajax and jQuery in general).

How could I solve this?
I would like to get the html as the one I see if I save the page from the browser.

That's my code:

```
import urllib.request

urlAddress = "http:// ... /"
getPage = urllib.request.urlopen(urlAddress)
outputPage = str(getPage.read())
print(outPage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't by just getting the page source from the server. You need to do one of the following:

- Use the headless browser or similar solution (Selenium, Splash, PhantomJS, ...) to run the JS code in the page itself and see the results.
- Figure out what the JS code actually does, and recreate the same in Python. If it's doing another call to the server, you can see that in the XHR tab in Developer Tools on Chrome.